# R: rendering xtable

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I have an .Rmd file containing:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(groupGrundALL))  
```
````

Using the "Knit Word" button in RStudio it creates and opens a Word file, but only shows the following text line instead of the intended (rendered) table itself:

% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package % Wed Oct 2111:14:28 2015

When I run in the console...

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(groupGrundALL))
```

I get LaTeX code:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Oct 21 11:16:48 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrrr}
\hline
& Retouren.Grund & Wert & Menge & Anzahl \\ 
\hline
1 & Fehlbestellung & 685395.00 & 11469.00 & 222 \\ 
2 & andere & 237581.00 & 4354.00 & 179 \\ 
3 & Abgelaufene Ware & 129780.00 & 3522.00 & 1077 \\ 
4 & beschädigte Ware & 37417.00 & 729.00 & 143 \\ 
5 & Falschlieferung & 9943.00 & 280.00 &  14 \\ 
6 & nicht abgeholt & 1471.00 & 21.00 &  11 \\ 
7 & weggezogen & 25.00 & 1.00 &   1 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I get the table itself rendered and shown in the Word document?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far as I know, `xtable` only supports HTML and LaTeX formats (with LaTeX being the default).  If you're rendering your document to a Word file, you need to pass your tables in markdown format.  As far as options for what to do now, here are a few you can consider (presented as code suitable for your markdown document):

If knitting to a Word document:

````
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
groupGrundALL <- 
  structure(list(Retouren.Grund = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 7L), .Label = c("Abgelaufene Ware", "andere", "beschadigte Ware", 
"Falschlieferung", "Fehlbestellung", "nicht abgeholt", "weggezogen"
), class = "factor"), Wert = c(685395, 237581, 129780, 37417, 
9943, 1471, 25), Menge = c(11469, 4354, 3522, 729, 280, 21, 1
), Anzahl = c(222, 179, 1077, 143, 14, 11, 1)), .Names = c("Retouren.Grund", 
"Wert", "Menge", "Anzahl"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

## `knitr::kable` 
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(groupGrundALL, format = "markdown")
```  

## `pixiedust`
For markdown tables, `pixiedust` is an extended wrapper for `knitr::kable` that allows you to do some additional formatting without having to preprocess data.

```{r, warning = FALSE}
library(pixiedust)
dust(groupGrundALL) %>%
  sprinkle_print_method("markdown")
```
````

If you're comfortable installing packages from GitHub, you can also use the `Grmd` package (`devtools::install_github("gforge/Grmd")`) and knit to a `docx_document`, which allows you to use the HTML output from `xtable`, `kable`, and `pixiedust`.  This means you can also have all the customizations of `xtable` and `pixiedust` available to you.  When the document is completed, it is saved as an HTML file, so you can either right click and open as a word document, or change the extension to .docx

````
---
title: "Sample Document 2"
output: Grmd::docx_document
---


```{r}
groupGrundALL <- 
  structure(list(Retouren.Grund = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 7L), .Label = c("Abgelaufene Ware", "andere", "beschadigte Ware", 
"Falschlieferung", "Fehlbestellung", "nicht abgeholt", "weggezogen"
), class = "factor"), Wert = c(685395, 237581, 129780, 37417, 
9943, 1471, 25), Menge = c(11469, 4354, 3522, 729, 280, 21, 1
), Anzahl = c(222, 179, 1077, 143, 14, 11, 1)), .Names = c("Retouren.Grund", 
"Wert", "Menge", "Anzahl"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

## `xtable` with HTML
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(groupGrundALL), type = "html")  
```  

## `knitr::kable` 
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(groupGrundALL, format = "html")
```  

## `pixiedust` with HTML
```{r, warning = FALSE}
library(pixiedust)
dust(groupGrundALL) %>%
  sprinkle_print_method("html")
```
````

I have a strong bias for `pixiedust` (obviously), but `knitr::kable` is probably the fastest way to deal with simple markdown tables that don't need much customization.

Comment: great! knitr::kable does the job for me but now I will learn about your fantastic pixiedust package... ...will post a question soon :-)

Comment: An update: `Grmd` has now been integrated into `Gmisc`, which is available on CRAN.