# how do you print xtable using knitr in word document

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to print xtable in using knitr in word document as follows:

```
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
  p1<-xtable(head(iris), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)
  print(p1)
```

I get this error, any ideas:

```
latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package % Mon Oct 26 11:17:22 2015
```

Comment: try removing the assisnment and print: `xtable(head(iris), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)`

Comment: I still see it on both word and pdf output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: rendering xtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255836/r-rendering-xtable)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with the standard `word_document` that comes with `rmarkdown`.  `xtable` only produces output in HTML and LaTeX formats.  To render a word document, your table has to be prepared in markdown format (so far as I know).

Some alternative options are to use `knitr::kable` or the `pixiedust` package.

If you're comfortable downloading things from GitHub, you may also use `devtools::install_github("gforge/Grmd")` and then replace `output:word_document` with `output: Grmd::docx_document`.  Then using `print.xtable` with `type = 'html'` will render to an HTML document that can be opened as a docx.

Comment: Word can usually interpret html tables as a Word table. In fact, if you open the word docx with a text editor and paste the html table inside, lo, it's formatted and pretty in word. I wonder why this hasn't been exploited by rmarkdown yet.