# Rendering xtable with significant digits

Tags: r, xtable, gridextra

I'd like to be able to render an xtable in an automatically run piece of code, i.e. NOT via copy-and-paste, while controlling the number of significant digits.  The only way that I know to render an xtable on a standard plot device is by using grid.table, but that method ignores the digits directive and plots all available digits.  Here's a code example.  Any advice?

```
library(xtable)
library(gridExtra)

x = rnorm(100)
y = x + rnorm(100)
m = lm(y ~ x)

print(xtable(m)) #too many decimal places
print(xtable(m, digits = 2)) #this works
grid.table(xtable(m, digits=2)) #this doesn't!!!
```

None of the bits of advice here seem useful for automated rendering:
[R: rendering xtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255836/r-rendering-xtable)

Comment: Do you need to render it on a plot device?

Comment: yes, I do.  I could probably find work-arounds for rendering to pdf, but that's not enough.  I need to be able to render to either one.

Comment: `xtable` produces a data.frame with further attributes that are used for formatting when printing to latex or html formats. `grid.table` ignores them altogether and only deals with the bare data.frame, so any number formatting has to be done on the data itself, e.g. with `sprintf` or `formatC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert everything to strings, you should be able to make this work:

```
x <- xtable(m)
x[] <- lapply(x, sprintf, fmt = "%0.2f")
grid.table(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of your final plot device, but for some purposes you can just skip `xtable` all together:

```
library("broom")
library("gridExtra")
x = rnorm(100)
y = x + rnorm(100)
m = lm(y ~ x)
DF <- broom::tidy(m)
DF[,2:4] <- round(DF[,2:4], 2)
DF[,5] <- format(DF[,5], scientific = TRUE, digits = 4)
grid.table(DF)
```

Make sure you have the latest `gridExtra`.  You can also control the appearance of the table in great detail, via themes (there is a vignette on the topic).

Comment: I'm already using a theme.  I'll try your way as well.  Thanks!